# Definition of derivative and cluster points

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, definition

The most general way to define the derivative of a real function is given as follows:

**Definition**$\;\mathbf{1}$. Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in X$ a cluster point (point of accumulation or limit point) of $X$. We say that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ when exists the limit
$$
f'(a):=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}. \tag{1}
$$
In affirmative case, the limit $f'(a)$ is said the derivative of $f$ at $a$.

**Remark**$\;\mathbf{1}.$ In Defintion $1$ the point $a \in X$ must be a cluster point of $X$ in order to ensure that the limit in $(1)$, if exists, is well-defined and unique.

On the other hand, for instance, in Definition $6.1.1$ (page $162$) of $[1]$,  Definition $1$ is considered for $X=I$ an interval. The reason for that, according the authors, is: *the concept is most naturally apparent for functions defined on intervals.* However, when $X$ is an interval is not considered $a \in X$ as a cluster point.

**Question**. Regarding this last affirmation: is this possible since every point in any interval is a cluster point?

$[1]$ Bartle, R. and Sherbert, S. Introduction to real analysis. 4th ed.

Comment: Definition 1, when considering functions defined on intervals (open or closed), there's no need to specify that $a$ is a cluster point because this is implied by the fact that you're working with an interval. The reason the authors of the book you mentioned may have omitted that detail is that it is a standard assumption in real analysis when dealing with intervals, and explicitly stating it for every point could be redundant. However, it's always a good practice to define your terms clearly if there's any potential for confusion.

Comment: I do not understand at all your “i[f] exi[s]ts, is well-defined and unique.”

Comment: @TedShifrin The limit may not exist, but if it does, with $a$ being an accumulation point, then the limit is well-defined and is unique (by limit property).

Comment: The point is that there is no definition of limit at a non-accumulation point. Well-defined and unique mean the same thing, by the way.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I know. That's why I wrote it as an remark, just to reinforce the reason why we need it to be an accumulation point so that the reader doesn't need to consult the limit definition.

Answer (score 0):

Given $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, denote by $X':=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \: ; \: x \: \text{is a cluster point of} \: X\}$.

For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$, let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be any of the following bounded intervals: $(a,b), (a,b], [a,b)$ and $[a,b]$. According item $i)$ of Example $2.1.1$ of $[2]$, we have $I'=[a,b]$. Thus, in this case, since $I \subset [a,b]=I'$, we conclude that every point of $I$ is a cluster point of $I$.

Now, if $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is one of the unbounded intervals $(a, \infty)$ or $[a, \infty)$, then according item $ii)$ of Example $2.1.1$ of $[2]$, we have $I'=[a, \infty)$. Thus, $I \subset [a, \infty)=I'$ and every point of $I$ is a cluster point of $I$.

Similarly, if $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is one of the unbounded intervals $(-\infty,b)$ or $(-\infty,b]$, by item $iii)$ of Example $2.1.1$ of $[2]$, every point of $I$ is a cluster point of $I$.

In any case, namely for bounded or unbounded intervals, we can conclude that every point of any interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a cluster point of $I$.

$[2]$ NAIR, M. Thamban; NAIR. *Calculus of one variable*. Second Edition. Springer International Publishing, $2021$.